# Name for generalization of Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula

Tags: terminology, lie-algebras

If the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula describes

$$Z(X,Y) = \log(\exp(X) \exp(Y)) = X + Y + \frac12 [X,Y] + \ldots$$

then what is the name for formulas of the type

$$Z(W,X,Y) = \log(\exp(W) \exp(X) \exp(Y)) = W + X + Y + \ldots? $$

Comment: Probably still the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, since there's no additional generality here. Namely because $\log(\exp(W)\exp(X)\exp(Y))$ can be computed using the top formula by writing $\exp(W)\exp(X) = \exp(V)$, where $V:=W+X+\frac12 [W,X]+...$.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks. I was just wondering if this has a specific name by which it is usually referred to.

Comment: It has no standard name, or a particularly evocative structure for that matter, if you are intent on google searching for it. For *Y= -W*, of course, it is the adjoint group action, and for *Y=W* it is sometimes dubbed the [triple CBH formula](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/CBH.pdf), but all these arise out of the conventional CBH algorithms.